# Why I get a negative false_negative count with Keras (e.g. -10)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I am trying to debug a keras model for binary classification of text that is performing very bad.

I turned off all the bells and whistlers, and I tried to fit it with two different datasets (same X data of my dataset, but different Y labels):

- Y0: with all Y=0
- Y1: with all Y=1

Around 1K samples for each dataset.

Then I tried to fit the model several times varying some parameters like learning rate, size of the layers, switching between one_hot and integer encoded representation of words.

Surprisingly this test revealed that some metrics are giving me wrong results:

[Stats of the model when fitted with Y0 and Y1 datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3zMU.png)

Why the FN count is negative?

I made some checks.
It seems that **the negative FalseNegative Count (e.g.:-87) affects the other metrics like, Recall (which is even > 1), MAE, Accuracy**

here is the (semplified) code I am running:

```py
import keras_metrics

DEFAULT_INNER_ACTIVATION = 'relu'
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ACTIVATION = 'softplus'

    def __init__(self, sentence_max_lenght, ctx_max_len, dense_features_dim, vocab_size):

        lstm_input_phrase = keras.layers.Input(shape=(sentence_max_lenght,), name='L0_STC_MyApp')

        lstm_emb_phrase = keras.layers.LSTM(DEFAULT_MODEL_L1_STC_DIM, name='L1_STC_MyApp')(lstm_emb_phrase)
        lstm_emb_phrase = keras.layers.Dense(DEFAULT_MODEL_L2_STC_DIM, name='L2_STC_MyApp', activation=DEFAULT_INNER_ACTIVATION)(lstm_emb_phrase)

        x = keras.layers.Dense(DEFAULT_MODEL_L3_DIM, activation=DEFAULT_INNER_ACTIVATION)(lstm_emb_phrase)
        x = keras.layers.Dense(DEFAULT_MODEL_L4_DIM, activation=DEFAULT_INNER_ACTIVATION)(x)

        main_output = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ACTIVATION)(x)

        self.model = keras.models.Model(inputs=lstm_input_phrase,
                                        outputs=main_output)

        optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=self.LEARNING_RATE)

        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy',
                                                                                     'mae',
                                                                                     keras_metrics.precision(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.recall(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_precision(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_recall(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_true_positive(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_true_negative(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_false_positive(),
                                                                                     keras_metrics.binary_false_negative()])


    def fit(self, x_lstm_phrase, x_lstm_context, x_lstm_pos, x_dense, y):

        x_arr = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_lstm_phrase)

        y_onehot = MyNN.onehot_transform(y)

        return self.model.fit(x_arr,
                       y_onehot,
                       batch_size=self.batch_size,
                       epochs=self.max_epochs,
                       validation_split=self.validation_split,
                       callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                                min_delta=0.0001,
                                                                patience=self.patience,
                                                                restore_best_weights=True
                                                                )])
```

This is a fragment of the first part of the output I am getting from my terminal:

Note: there are two warnings here. I do not consider these warns effecting the issue.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-04-01 23:26:59.479064: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:From [path_to_myApp]\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (f
rom tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From [path_to_myApp]\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.p
ython.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

 16/618 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 0.7756 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5007 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 16.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
 32/618 [>.............................] - ETA: 23s - loss: 0.7740 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.5000 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 32.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
 48/618 [=>............................] - ETA: 17s - loss: 0.7725 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4994 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 48.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
 64/618 [==>...........................] - ETA: 15s - loss: 0.7711 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4988 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 64.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
 80/618 [==>...........................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 0.7697 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4982 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 80.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
 96/618 [===>..........................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.7682 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4976 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 96.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
112/618 [====>.........................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.7666 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4970 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 112.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
128/618 [=====>........................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.7650 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4963 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 128.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
144/618 [=====>........................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.7634 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4956 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 144.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00 
160/618 [======>.......................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.7617 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4949 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 160.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
176/618 [=======>......................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.7600 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4941 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 176.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
192/618 [========>.....................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.7582 - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.4934 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 192.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
```

This is when I start getting a negative count of FN:

```
256/618 [===========>..................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3052 - binary_accuracy: 0.8750 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2778 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 256.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
272/618 [============>.................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.2965 - binary_accuracy: 0.8824 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2791 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 272.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
288/618 [============>.................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.2882 - binary_accuracy: 0.8889 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2807 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 288.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
304/618 [=============>................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2804 - binary_accuracy: 0.8947 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2828 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 304.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
320/618 [==============>...............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2730 - binary_accuracy: 0.9000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2853 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 320.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
336/618 [===============>..............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2659 - binary_accuracy: 0.9048 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2882 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0000 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0000 - true_positive: 336.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: 0.0000e+00
352/618 [================>.............] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.2591 - binary_accuracy: 0.8864 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2914 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0455 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0455 - true_positive: 368.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -16.0000  
368/618 [================>.............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.2526 - binary_accuracy: 0.8696 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2950 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.0870 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.0870 - true_positive: 400.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -32.0000
384/618 [=================>............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.2464 - binary_accuracy: 0.8542 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2989 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.1250 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.1250 - true_positive: 432.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -48.0000
400/618 [==================>...........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.2404 - binary_accuracy: 0.8400 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3031 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.1600 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.1600 - true_positive: 464.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -64.0000
416/618 [===================>..........] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.2346 - binary_accuracy: 0.8269 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3076 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.1923 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.1923 - true_positive: 496.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -80.0000
432/618 [===================>..........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.2291 - binary_accuracy: 0.8148 - mean_absolute_error: 0.3124 - precision: 1.0000 - recall: 1.2222 - precision_1: 1.0000 - recall_1: 1.2222 - true_positive: 528.0000 - true_negative: 0.0000e+00 - false_positive: 0.0000e+00 - false_negative: -96.0000
```

Do you know how can I fix this issue?

### EDIT:

I tried to remove every keras_metrics used, leaving only the binary_accuracy.

Still getting the issue, since **Loss and Val_Loss are going down to almost zero, while Accuracies are stuck to around 0.5.**

Considering the datasets peculiarity, it means the #TP = #FN (for Y1) and #TN + #FP (for Y0)

How can it be possible to have this accuracy measure with this loss measure?

Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am using a

```
Dense(2, activation='softplus')
```

layer as output?

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What metrics implementation are you using? Keras doesn't have the metrics you use (like false positives, etc).

Comment: I am using keras_metrics module. Do you have experience with this module?

Comment: Irrelevant to your issue, but MAE is for regression problems only, and it actually has no place in a classification problem, like here

Comment: You are right desertnaut. I removed the metrics as explained in the EDIT above.

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I changed the activation function from softplus to softmax.

All metrics are now within a correct range even though the classifier is performing poorly.

/H